# How can I move this table up?

Tags: tables, math-mode, equations, formatting

Im having trouble moving my equations next to my table

code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[38]

\begin{align}
\int{e^{\sqrt{x}}}, y = \sqrt{x} \ \rightarrow dy = \frac{1}{2y} dx   \Leftrightarrow \int{2ye^ydy}
\end{align}

 \begin{tabular}{||c c||} 
 \hline
D &  I \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 2y & $e^y$\\ 
 \hline
 2 & $e^y$ \\
 \hline
 0 & $e^y$ \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{align}
\int{2ye^ydy} = 2ye^y - 2\int{e^ydy} \\
         \rightarrow  2ye^y - 2e^y + C\\
\boxed{2\sqrt{x}e^{\sqrt{x}} - 2e^{\sqrt{x}} + C}
\end{align}

\end{enumerate}
```

Here is image to go with my question
[image: Table to move]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (Observe that I've stuck the four equations in a `minipage`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[38.] 
\addtocounter{equation}{6}
 \quad$\begin{array}{||c c||} 
 \hline
 D  &  I \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 2y & e^y\\ 
 \hline
 2  & e^y \\
 \hline
 0  & e^y \\
 \hline
\end{array}$
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\int e^{\sqrt{x}},\ y = \sqrt{x} 
  \quad \rightarrow \quad
  dy = \frac{1}{2y}\,dx  \Leftrightarrow \int 2ye^y\,dy\\
\int 2ye^y\,dy = 2ye^y - 2\int e^y\,dy \\
\rightarrow  2ye^y - 2e^y + C \\
\boxed{2\sqrt{x}e^{\sqrt{x}} - 2e^{\sqrt{x}} + C}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Im going so save this post!